# Zend framework 3 ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-framework3

How would you write the following query in **Zend framework 3** ?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, 'a','b','c');
```

**I tried**

```
$select->order(new Expression("FIELD(field_name, 'a', 'b', 'c')"),field_name);
```

but not moves...

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake somewhere, make sure that you've:

- Imported `Expression` correctly with `use`.
- removed the second argument form `order()`, there is none.

`Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` is the correct way to extend a query with DBMS-specific expressions.

With the following test script I get your expected result:

```
$platform = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();
$select = new Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->from(['t' => 'table_name']);
$select->order(
    new Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(sprintf(
        "FIELD(t.%s, 'a', 'b', 'c')",
        $platform->quoteIdentifier('field_name')
    ))
);

var_dump($select->getSqlString($platform));
```

Result is:

```
string(81) "SELECT `t`.* FROM `table_name` AS `t` ORDER BY FIELD(t.`field_name`, 'a', 'b', 'c')"
```

Few notes here:

- Replace the `Zend` namespace with `Laminas` when you using Laminas instead.
- Make sure you always quote identifiers with `quoteIdentifier()` from the platform instance (you should be able to receive the platform from your table or DB instance).
- Use table aliases where you can, as an extra level of security against SQL Injections and they also make your life easier.
- On big tables with thousand of rows I guess you're query will get very slow. So you can either add an index and if this doesn't work create another column with the pre-calculated value from `FIELD()` (you can either do this in your application or on the DDL level).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using expression, can you give string to order method

```
$select->order("FIELD(field_name, 'a', 'b', 'c')");
```

If field name is a variable

```
$select->order("FIELD(" . $field_name . ", 'a', 'b', 'c')");
```

If the issue still persists, then we can trace the issue by printing the query

```
$select->query()->__toString()

or 

$select->__toString();
```

dont remember the query exactly, you can try them

Comment: did you check the query toString(). what is the query ?

Comment: When printing the query `ORDER BY FIELD(field_name , "a")`
but I think there is a connect error in ZF3